# Substance Painter material looks fine in Eve but broken in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I created some textures in Substance Painter and imported them not blender. In Eevee they look fine, but broken in Cycles.
Eevee:
[image: The material in Eevee]
Cycles:
[image: The material in Cycles]

Node Tree:
[image: Node Tree]

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: So after some playing around it seems that GPU rendering is the issue. Im on 3.2 alpha and using a MacBook Pro M1Max Chip. when I switch to CPU rendering it looks fine.

Comment: Remember that Substance Painter uses DirectX for it's shader systems whereas Blender uses OpenGL. In many instances, _DIrectX>OpenGL_ conversion is necessary for Normal Maps (Separate XYZ of Normal Map, subtract Y from 1 in a math node, then recombine).